# Why does the class fields update their data after the method works

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

Help me please.
Let's say I have a Link class for linked lists.
And there is the SortedList class where there are methods for working with data created by the first class.

```
public class Link {
public long db;
public Link next;
public Link(long data){
    db=data;
}
public void displayLink(){
    System.out.println(db+" ");
}
}


   public class SortedList {    
   private Link first;  
   public SortedList(){  
   first=null;    
   }
   public void insert(long key){
    Link newLink=new Link(key);
    Link previous=null;
    Link current=first;
    while (current!=null&&key>=current.db){
        previous=current;
        current=current.next;
    }
    if (previous==null){
        first=newLink;
    }else {
        previous.next=newLink;
        newLink.next=current;
    }

  }
public void displayList(){
    System.out.println("List (first-->last): ");
    Link current=first;
    while (current!=null){
        current.displayLink();
        current=current.next;
    }
    System.out.println();
}
  }
```

The insert method uses the first field.
The first field passes its data to the current field.
After the method exits with the current field, no changes are made to the first field, but the changes still appear in the first field.

How it happens, I pray you help

Comment: Please edit your question to add this information. Also, your question is currently not really understandable. Please edit it to make it clearer.

Comment: Konrad, sorry.
In a nutshell.
I don’t understand how the data of the first field of the SortedList class is updated after the insert method works.
After all, no information is saved in the insert method for the first field.

Comment: What do you mean by “After all, no information is saved in the insert method for the first field”? The code *does* save information in `first`, when it does `first = newLink;`.

Comment: if we add data to the sortedList class like this
sortedList.insert(1);
sortedList.insert(6); 
and display the data to the console, then the output will be like this
List (first-->last): 
1 
6 
the question here is how the first field stores all the information passed through the insert method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the beginning of `insert`, we set `current` to be a reference to the value of `first`. This means that, at this point, both `current` and `first` are references to the same field.

The `while` loop then iterates over the nodes starting from `first` until we either hit the end of the list or a node whose key is less than `key`. The iteration happens by updating `current` to follow the `next` reference of the current node.

Now happens the part that confused you: if `first` was `null` (i.e. the first time we call `insert`, the next operation updates `first` by assigning it a new value. `first` will now refer to the value of `newLink`, which is precisely the node that we created at the top of `insert`.

It helps to take pen and paper, draw a table with columns for all variables, [and go through the algorithm step by step](https://blog.pragmaticengineer.com/paper-debugging/), like a computer would. You can do something similar by using the debugger, set a break point at the beginning of the method, and “step through” your code.

Comment: Aaaa, like a butt on the head.
You are a very cool guy, even though I explained as a child, you could understand me. Thank you very much)